# How to receive a mosquitto message using a libuv poll?

Tags: c, linux, mosquitto, libuv

1. I am currently writing a mqtt message reception code using libuv poll and mosquitto client. The development environment is Linux, and the following is part of my code.

```c
// mosquitto lib init
static bool mqttInit(mosquittoInfo* mosqInfo)
{
    int connected  = 0;
    int mqttSocket = -1;
    struct mosquitto* mosq = NULL;

    mosquitto_lib_init();
    mosqInfo->mosq = mosquitto_new(NULL, true, NULL);

    if (!mosqInfo->mosq)
    {
        return false;
    }

    mosquitto_connect_callback_set(mosqInfo->mosq, connectCallback);
    //mosquitto_message_callback_set(mosqInfo->mosq, messageCallback);
    connected = mosquitto_connect(mosqInfo->mosq, HOST, PORT, 60);

    printf("connected Result %d", connected);

    if (connected != MOSQ_ERR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return false;
    }

    mosquitto_subscribe(mosqInfo->mosq, nullptr, "#", 0);
    mosqInfo->mosqSocket = mosquitto_socket(mosqInfo->mosq);

    if (mosqInfo->mosqSocket == -1)
    {
        printf("%d", errno);
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

// libuv poll handler
static void mqttPollHandler(uv_poll_t* poll, int status, int events)
{
    int loopResult  = 0;
    int readResult  = 0;
    int writeResult = 0;
    char buffer[75] = { '\0' };
    mosquittoInfo* mosqInfo = NULL;

    if (status < 0)
    {
        gets("error handling mqtt socket\n");
        return;
    }

    mosqInfo   = (mosquittoInfo*)poll->data;
    loopResult = mosquitto_loop_misc(mosqInfo->mosq);

    if (events & UV_READABLE)
    {
        readResult = mosquitto_loop_read(mosqInfo->mosq, 1);
        printf("readResult %d\n", readResult);

        char buffer[75] = { '\0'};
        int r = recv(mosqInfo->mosqSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);

        printf("%s\n", buffer);
    }
}


int main()
{

    int mqttSocket;

    uv_loop_t loop;
    uv_poll_t poll;
    mosquittoInfo mosqInfo;

    uv_loop_init(&loop);
    mqttInit(&mosqInfo);

    if (mosqInfo.mosqSocket == 0)
    {
        printf("error getting mosquitto socket\n");
        return 0;
    }
    
    uv_poll_init_socket(&loop, &poll, mosqInfo.mosqSocket);
    poll.data = &mosqInfo;
    uv_poll_start(&poll, UV_READABLE | UV_WRITABLE, mqttPollHandler);

    return uv_run(&loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT);

}
```

2. Problem: There was a problem reading the mqtt message normally. I tried reading using the recv() function, but the entire message was not read. Additionally, even if the buffer size was modified, the results were the same. The following are contents of transmission and reception messages.

```c
published message : {"cmd":84,"userID":"test@test.com","devID":"test"}
subscribed message : @test.com", "devID":"test"}
```

3. I want to read the mqtt message normally. Please point out if there is anything wrong or wrong. I'll fix that part.

Comment: Why are you trying to re-implement the network loop? The client will handle all that for you. Also with `mosquitto_loop_read`  the final argument is the number of network packets not messages to read so you are very likely get partial messages.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I`m working on a pi(ubuntu) project based on single threads and thinking about whether libuv and mosquitto will be available.